# implement pow in java without using math lib

Tags: java, math

I did a code like this:

```
public static double myPow(double x, int n){
    if(n==0) return 1;
    double t = myPow(x, n/2);
    if(n % 2 != 0){
        if(n < 0){
            return (1 / t * t * x);
        } else {
            return t * t * x;
        }
    } else {
        return t * t;
    }
}
```

Why isn't this java code working. I translated a working cpp code to java version. But it failed like this:

Input: 34.00515, -3 Output: 1.00000 Expected: 0.00003

P.S.
this is the working cpp version:

```
class Solution {
public:
    double power(double x, int n)  
    {  
       if (n == 0)  
         return 1;  
       double v = power(x, n / 2);  
       if (n % 2 == 0)  
         return v * v;  
       else  
         return v * v * x;  
     }  
     double pow(double x, int n) {  
       // Start typing your C/C++ solution below  
       // DO NOT write int main() function  
       if (n < 0)  
         return 1.0 / power(x, -n);  
       else  
         return power(x, n);      
     }  
};
```

Comment: In Java, `1/2*3*4` is `0`, since it uses integer arithmetic by default.  Try casting your literal `1` to a double.

Comment: @Marco13 no, that would be right. The input of n is integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering if `n` is negative in the `n % 2 != 0` case, but not in the `else` case.  To make it clearer, I would handle it in a different recursive case.  Take the negative `n` handling out of the `if` block, and add this line after the `if(n == 0)` line.

```
if (n < 0) return 1 / myPow(x, -n);
```

This also eliminates the integer division you were doing in this line: `return (1 / t * t * x);`.  It also had the error that you would have divided by `t`, multiplied by `t`, then multiplied by `x`, instead of dividing by the entire product.

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be faster at higher powers than your solution:

```
public static double posIntPow(final double pVal, final int pPow) {
    double ret = 1;
    double v1, v2;
    int n = pPow;
    v1 = pVal;
    if ((n & 1) == 1) {
        ret = pVal;
    }
    n = n >>> 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        v2 = v1 * v1;
        if ((n & 1) == 1) {
            ret = ret * v2;
        }
        v1 = v2;
        n = n >>> 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And about 10 times faster than the normal Math lib one - though this obviously only does integer. Can use same test you used for negative.